# Is there a way to avoid view type erasure when implementing the view style pattern?

Tags: swiftui

Is there any trick that Apple uses to avoid style body type erasure?

I'm assuming a typical style modifier method just passes the style through environment.

```
func buttonStyle<S>(_ style: S) -> some View where S: ButtonStyle {
    environment(\.buttonStyle, AnyButtonStyle(style))
}
```

where `AnyButtonStyle` wraps body made of the wrapped style into `AnyView`.

If my assumption is wrong, how do they pass a style down into a view hierarchy without losing specialized type of the style?

If my assumption is correct, it seems like basically most views (Label, Button, Picker, List, Toggle, TextField...) must be resolved in a view graph from `AnyView` since their bodies are made type erased from a style. How it isn't too bad for the view graph resolver?

Comment: I don't know how it actually works, but I assume it has something to do with `AnyView(_fromValue: Text("Hello!") as Any)`. You can pass in a view of type `Any`, and it will be converted to `AnyView`. You can see an example of this in use [here](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor). Also, if you use `Mirror` for reflection of some views, you can see that the `buttonStyle` modifier does _not_ individually apply that modifier to each view below in the hierarchy. It is _likely_ some sort of `@Environment` value, as you assumed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not. In fact, if you look at the documentation for [ButtonStyleConfiguration.Label](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyleconfiguration/label-swift.property) you'll see that Apple is actually using type erasure themselves:

> `struct Label`
>     A type-erased label of a button.

Type erasure is explicitly mentioned for many other SwiftUI `SomeStyle.Configuration` types, though not all of them. But if you look at their definitions they have no generic parameters.

```swift
@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
public struct LabelStyleConfiguration {

    /// A type-erased title view of a label.
    public struct Title {
        public typealias Body = Never
    }

    /// A type-erased icon view of a label.
    public struct Icon {
        public typealias Body = Never
    }

    public var title: LabelStyleConfiguration.Title { get }
    public var icon: LabelStyleConfiguration.Icon { get }
}
```